# Production build throws unexpected errors

Tags: java, node.js, spring, angular, production-environment

few days ago I build my `Angular 4` and `Spring Boot` app with `npm run build` and everything works, but now I got an error like this:

```
ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in C:/Users/Michał/IdeaProjects/Inventory/src/main/frontend/src/app/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object]).

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\Michał\IdeaProjects\Inventory\src\main\frontend\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

my `data.service` class looks:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllWithPaging(params: HttpParams){
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/withPaging?' + params.toString());
  }

  insertOrUpdate(resources){
    return this.http.post(this.url, resources);
  }

  delete(resources){
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + resources.id, {responseType: 'text'});
  }

  get getUrl() : string{
    return this.url;
  }

  get getHttp(): HttpClient{
    return this.http
  }
```

What has changed since one week?

Comment: The constructor is supposed to be used for injection... It doesn't know what you want to inject for `string`

Comment: Hmm so how to deal with it? I have a second service which extends above and in constructor I provide `url` in string

Comment: Don't pass in url. Set the url property directly. On the child class

Comment: Works nice,thanks! BTW: way two days ago it works fine?